# Uncaught TypeError: (...).modal is not a function in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, ecmascript-6

I need another pair of eyes and knowledge since I'm new to ES6.

Here's my `index.js` file where I try to use fullcalendar.io:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'fullcalendar';
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     // ... 

     eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

         $('#calendarEventModal').modal();
     }
    })     
})
```

The problem is that when I run this code and click on the event I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).modal is not a function`

What am I doing wrong? What is missing ?

Comment: Try: `import $ from 'jquery'; window.jQuery = window.$ = $; import 'bootstrap'; ...`

Comment: @Andreas - thanks for the hint, but I tried and it did not work :( - still the same error ....

Comment: Could it be possible that the issue is caused by multiple jQuery imports? The main template is importing jQuery ....

Comment: missing the modal from `bootstrap` and once you add that try to clear the cache and check.

Comment: Could you update the question to display your current markup?

Comment: I think you might need to check bootstrap module has proper files. https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two cases in which `$('#calendarEventModal')` does not have a `modal()` method:

- `#calendarEventModal` does not match an element in DOM at the time the method is called (to check you could use:

```js
if ($('#calendarEventModal').is('#calendarEventModal')) {
  console.log('i has found zee DOM element'); 
  $('#calendarEventModal').modal();
} else {
  console.log('no joy. `#calendarEventModal` missing in action...'); 
}
```

...obviously, you don't need the `console.log()` ).
In simpler words: do you have an element with `id="calendarEventModal"` in your DOM, holding the contents of whatever you want to see in your modal at the time `.modal()` is called?
Is it placed, by any chance, **inside** `#calendar`? If so, perhaps you should take it out. I don't know what `.fullCalendar()` performs on an element, but chances are it replaces its `innerHTML` with some generated markup, thus trashing your `#calendarEventModal`.

- imported `'bootstrap'` package does not have a `modal()` method - it's possible to create custom Bootstrap packages not including all modules. However, it is included by default so, if you didn't trim the package down, chances are you're facing first case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints! I have tried and indeed there is the right DOM element inside $('#calendarEventModal'). I will try to check if bootstrap has the modal() method, but I don't see a reason why it should not?!